# Interactive game using Prolog, can you solve it? :)

Tags: prolog

I'm working on a task to develop predicates to help play this two player   game outlined below.

**Problem**

A 2 person game is played with a set of identical stones arranged into a number of heaps. There may be any number of stones and any number of heaps. A move in this game consists of either removing any number of stones from one heap, or removing an equal number of stones from each of 2 heaps. The loser of this game is the player who picks up the last stone.

e.g
three heaps of sizes 3,2,1, there are 10 possible moves, leading to the below states:

```
Take from first heap only: [2,2,1],[1,2,1],[2,1]
Taking from 2nd heap only: [3,1,1],[3,1]
Taking from the 3rd heap only: [3,2]
Taking from the 1st and 2nd heaps: [2,1,1], [1,1]
Taking from the 1st and 3rd heaps: [2,2]
Taking from the 2nd and 3rd heaps: [3,1]

[3,1] occurs twice because there are three different ways of reaching it in one move.
```

**Task1**

Create a predicate move (S1,S2) that upon backtracking returns all states S2 reachable from S1 in one move.

**So far what we have**

```
change([_|T],T).

change([H|T],[H1|T]):-
between(1,H,W),
H1 is H-W,
W<H.

change([H|T],[H|T1]):-
change(T,T1).

change2([H|T],[H1|T1]):-
between(0,H,W),
H1 is H-W,
W<H,
change(T,T1).
```

So this produces results that will take any number of stones from any individual list and currently will take a differing number of stones from differing lists. So currently I cant get it to work where you want to take the same number of stones from differing lists.

I.e if I had [1,4,1,3] I'd like to be able to end up with [4,3].

Any help would be really appreciated on this task :).